# Relationship between the multiple possible configuration of domain name servers

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns

There are many (IMHO, too many) places to configure the DNS server(s) used and I am not sure about the relationship between them. A few questions are: Which configurations are only queried conditionally (For example, if I understand correctly, the systemd configuration is not queried if the corresponding service is not running)? Which configurations override which? What is the recommended way to configure DNS?

To name a few places to configure the DNS server(along with some other information I know about them, which should kindly be corrected if there is any misunderstanding),

1. Write in `/etc/resolv.conf` and use `chattr` to force it to remain persistent after reboot (I think this one is discouraged)
2. `resolvconf`. Config in the various files in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d`. Use `resolvconf -a` to add a DNS and `resolvconf -u` to update it
3. `systemd-resolve(d)`, a unit of `systemd`. Config in `/etc/systemd/resolvd.conf`. It uses the address `127.0.0.53` as the dummy DNS solver in `/etc/resolv.conf`. The real `resolv.conf` is found in `/var/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`. In newer versions (since which version?), `systemd-resolve --status` can be used to query the current DNS status.
4. `/etc/network/interfaces`. This one is related to `/etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/networking.service`
5. `Network-Manager`, a component that drives the network configuration context menu in GUI. If an interface is configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`, it will refuse to manage it again (shown as `not managed` in the GUI context menu).

I am running `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` with Unity desktop environment.

Comment: I would probably broke down the question, and investigate (and ask) it into smaller bits to make the whole picture. Too many questions asked here.

Comment: It all depend on what you want to do ...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I believe I am most interested in "Which one overrides which".

Comment: Ultimately your answer is in `grep '^hosts:' /etc/nsswitch.conf`. Whatever this says is where your DNS comes from.

Comment: @Patrick Thank you. Would you turn it into an answer?

Comment: They did not appear all overnight, you have to take into account history: from ancient times unix systems used `/etc/resolv.conf` then (not necessarily strictly in this order), `resolvconf` was created to allow easily to  change the DNS when you change the network, graphical interfaces like Network Manager appeared to help people that prefer GUI over CLI, and then systemd appeared with later its systemd-resolve process.

Comment: Thank you for your comment from a historical perspective. It is really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the recommended way to configure DNS?
>
> ...
>
> I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Unity desktop environment.

*Where possible*, it would be recommended for you to use this one:

> 5. Network-Manager, a component that drives the network configuration context menu in GUI.

For example, this is what the official Ubuntu Desktop Guide says.  I have not verified this is up to date, but I have no reason to doubt it.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/net-manual.html.en

> If your network doesn’t automatically assign network settings to your computer, you may have to manually enter the settings yourself. This topic assumes that you already know the correct settings to use. If not, you may need to ask your network administrator or look at the settings of your router or network switch.
>
> **To manually set your network settings:**
>
> ...
>
> 7. In the DNS section ...

---

On most systems, the only place the system will look is the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`.  (But there may be various different systems which edit the contents of this file).

As pointed out by Patrick, on some systems there will be a higher-priority plugin seen in `grep '^hosts:' /etc/nsswitch.conf`.  `dns` is the standard glibc plugin which reads `/etc/resolv.conf`.

In particular, if you have `resolve` before `dns`, this refers to `systemd-resolved`.  It will try to access `systemd-resolved` before using the DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

As you point out, it's possible to look at the DNS servers, if any, which `systemd-resolved` might query, by running `systemd-resolve --status`.

As you point out, the NetworkManager method is not expected to be compatible with manual edits to `/etc/resolv.conf` (as NetworkManager will edit this file itself).  Of course if you block NetworkManager from editing `/etc/resolv.conf`, the NetworkManager method will not work.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed information. What is the position of `/etc/network/interfaces` among the others? Another thing is that, while I know that `/etc/resolv.conf` is the only place the system will look up in most cases, it is not an deal place to do *configuration* because it is often overwritten by other configuration components.

Comment: @WeijunZhou More generally, it is recommended you only use one configuration method to set DNS servers (with manual editing being one method), so you don't have to worry about conflicts per se. `resolvconf` was used to provide an intermediary configuration system that accepted information from multiple configuration systems e.g. DHCP client, VPN software, and PPP (for modems). But if you use NetworkManager, that effectively does the same thing. Nowadays, if you have to fiddle with resolvconf, it suggests you're doing something weird and obscure.

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` and resolvconf are not systemd-resolve, do not have their own NSS module for nsswitch. Therefore they edit resolv.conf. `/etc/network/interfaces` (ifupdown) is one of the configuration systems that resolvconf knows how to intercept automatically when you install `resolvconf`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your further explanation. That makes it clearer.